# Acrescentar +1 toda vez que clicar no botão?

Tags: contador

Olá! Minha dúvida é a seguinte: gostaria de que, cada vez que clicar no botão, acrescente mais um no meu badge, eis o código:

HTML:  `<button id="buttonAdd"type="button"></button>`

HTML da badge (onde a alteração será feita):

```
<a href="pagamentos.html"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i><span class="badge badge-success" 
                id="carrinhoIndex">?</span></a>
```

JS:

```
var count = 0;
$('#buttonAdd').click(function(){
  alert(count);
  count++;
});
```

Aparentemente o código está certo, mas não funciona. A versão que estou usando do bootstrap e javascript obtive no site do bootstrap, portanto não sei qual o problema (outra funcionalidade do javascript funcionam)

O alert ali é pra verificar se o código está funcionando, mas não está.

Eu tentei usar a função:
HTML: `onclick="Acrescentar()";`

```
var cont=0; 
function Acrescentar() { 
$("#carrinhoIndex").text(cont); 
cont++;; 
}
```

E funcionou, mas não soma +1 toda vez que clica.

Versão JQuery, Bootstrap e JavaScript:

JQUERY:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

BOOTSTRAP:

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script src="js/js.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A sua lógica está certa.
Como você não listou a função acrescentar, resolvi criar uma com base no código que você postou.
Segue uma versão funcional do contador.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  carrinhoIndex.innerHTML = 0
})

var count = 0;

function acrescentar() { 
  count++;
  carrinhoIndex.innerHTML = count
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button id="buttonAdd" type="button" onclick="acrescentar()">Acrescentar</button>

<a href="pagamentos.html">
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
  <span class="badge badge-success" id="carrinhoIndex">?</span>
</a>
```

Comment: O seu exemplo funcionou, muito obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Via jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/jxved9o6/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  var badge = $('#carrinhoIndex');
  badge.text(count);
  $(document).on('click', '#buttonAdd', function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    count++;
    badge.text(count)
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/1.2.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonAdd"type="button">ADICIONAR</button>
    <a href="pagamentos.html">
    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    <span class="badge badge-success" id="carrinhoIndex">?</span></a>
```

Answer (score -2):

O seu código está certo mas você não está atualizando o valor visualmente, você só está atualizando o valor da variável mas não está mostrando a mesma atualizada.
Após o acréscimo na variável.
Tente após o acrescimo:
$("SUA BADGE").html(cont);

Answer (score -3):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  carrinhoIndex.innerHTML = 0
})

var count = 0;

function acrescentar() { 
  count++;
  carrinhoIndex.innerHTML = count
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button id="buttonAdd" type="button" onclick="acrescentar()">Acrescentar</button>

<a href="pagamentos.html">
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
  <span class="badge badge-success" id="carrinhoIndex">?</span>
</a>
```